# Terminal line resetting after about 50 characters

Tags: terminal

My command line prompt will reset after around 50 characters, including the prompt. For example, if the prompt looks like:

```
user@computer$
```

and I start to type

```
user@computer$ blah blah blah blah blah blah
```

I'll eventually get to the point where the command line starts to reset like so:

```
blah blmputer$ blah blah blah blah blah blah
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it? Originally I thought it was a problem with iTerm, but I looked at the default OS X terminal and was having the same problem.

Edit: Looking into it more I'm realizing that the line always resets a fixed amount of characters from the end of the window, not from the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual reason for this is due to not quoting escape sequences used to color or highlight your prompt in the `bash` shell.  If you do not do that, `bash` counts the escape characters as "printing".  The same would apply for `zsh` (different quoting), but `bash` happens to be the default shell with OSX.

According to the [`xterm`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h3-Changing-Colors) manual:

- bash  treats  characters within "[" and "]" as nonprinting (using no width on the screen).
- zsh treats characters within "%{" and "%}" as nonprinting.

The place to change is your shell's definition of `PS1`.  The *[Bash Prompt HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/)* is a good place to read more.